# Rmarkdown to create tabs in document not working when uploading as a wordpress post

Tags: html, css, r, wordpress, r-markdown

I have a Wordpress website for my podcast, www.ghccpod.com, and have produced an r-markdown script for it. I try to render it using RWordPress and knit2wp, but the out of the file has several issues, none of which I can find good solutions on this site. The one I want to ask about here is how to get the css tabs working when uploading the rmd as a wordpress post

I have the following code

```
---
title: "The Global Childhood Cancer Puzzle is Taking Shape"
subtitle: "The new view from the edge"
output:
  html_document:
    mathjax: default
---
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = FALSE)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
library(rethinking)
library(janitor)
library(gramr)
library(plotly)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(waffle)
library(gganimate)
library(ggpol)
library(ggforce)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)
library(gghighlight)
library(RWordPress)
```

`###` {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}
`####` Fig. 1 - tab
(its not quoted in the document - I can't figure out how to get stackoverflow to display the `#`)

```
some code
```

Then I will load it onto my website using RWordPress:

```
library(RWordpress)
library(knitr)

options(WordpressLogin = c(myusername = 'mypassword'),
        WordpressURL = 'https://www.ghccpod.com/xmlrpc.php')

knit2wp('test.RmD',
        title = 'Test Post',
        publish = FALSE,
        action = "newPost")
```

When I load it onto my website using something similar to the above code I get this abomination: (password is test) - https://www.ghccpod.com/the-global-childhood-cancer-puzzle-is-taking-shape-edge-1/
Among other problematic output on my page, I get this ugly code thing:
{.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

```
some code
```

My question is how do I get the tabs to display properly (it works when I knit the rmd to an html document and load that into my browser). Thank you so much for your help.